# How to align geom_point, geom_bar and geom_errobar with position_dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to produce a plot in ggplot for multinomial logistic regression. Not all levels of my nominal dependent variable are observed in each factor level. I want a plot that has even width of bars. I can get the mean of each factor to show up using geom_bar with even width bars once I use the `position_dodge(preserve='single')` code, but I cannot get the `geom_point` to align the same.

Here is my data and decide is the nominal dependent variable:

```
decide=c("h", "g", "h", "g", "h", "g", "g", "h", "g", "h", "g", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "g", "h", "h", "r", "g", "h", "h", "h", "g", "g", "g", "h", "h", "h","h", "h", "h", "r", "h", "g", "g", "h", "g", "h", "g", "h", "g", "h", "d", "h", "h", "r", "h", "h", "g", "g", "g", "h", "g", "g", "g", "g", "h", "h")
dcsz=c("small",  "medium", "small",  "small",  "medium", "small",  "small",  "medium", "medium", "small",  "small",  "medium", "small",  "medium", "small",  "medium", "small", "medium", "small",  "small",  "medium", "small",  "medium", "medium", "medium", "small",  "small",  "medium", "small",  "medium", "small",  "medium", "small",  "medium", "medium", "medium", "small",  "medium", "medium", "small",  "medium", "small",  "medium", "medium", "small",  "small",  "medium", "small",  "medium", "medium", "medium", "small",  "small",  "small",  "small",  "medium", "medium", "small",  "small",  "medium")
disthome=c(9.2,10.0,5.0,0.8,6.5,2.0,6.8,1.6,6.9,4.4,5.8,6.2,4.7,0.6,3.0,4.7,5.8,1.5,5.8,4.5,3.2,4.6,2.9,4.1,6.5,4.8,9.1,4.7,4.3,4.2,4.8,3.5,5.4,7.1,3.0,5.3,1.0,5.2,2.2,1.7,6.0,6.1,3.1,2.4,4.3,5.1,7.2,9.8,6.9,3.1,8.8,0.9,9.7,2.2,5.4,4.4,6.8,8.3,5.4,2.2)

gohome=data.frame(decide, dcsz, disthome)
```

Here is how I got the mean and standard error:

```
gohome.disthome <- gohome %>% 
  group_by(dcsz,decide) %>%
  summarise(meandisthome = mean(na.omit(disthome)), 
            sedisthome=sd(na.omit(disthome))/sqrt(n()))
```

Now to the nitty gritty:
Here is my original code before I managed to align the error bars with the means bar and separated the points into nominal variables:

```
ggplot(gohome,aes(y=disthome, x=dcsz, fill = decide)) +
  #add bars and the preserve part keeps all bars same width
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(),
           data=gohome.disthome,aes(x=dcsz,y=meandisthome))
  #overlay data points
  geom_point(position=position_dodge()) +
  #add error bars of means
  geom_errorbar(data=gohome.disthome,stat="Identity",
                position=position_dodge(),
                aes(x=dcsz, fill = decide,y=meandisthome,
                    ymin=meandisthome-sedisthome,ymax=meandisthome+sedisthome),
                    width=0.3)+
  #flip axis
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Here is the code where I got the error bars to align with the mean bars (using 0.9 in `position_dodge`), separated the points into nominal variable (0.9), and also got the error bars and mean bars to all be the same width even though the levels of the dependent variable were not all observed in each factor level (I added `preserve="single"` in `position_dodge`). I cannot add `preserve='single'` into the `geom_point` otherwise it does not separate the points by nominal variable, and using `preserve='total'` doesn't do anything either:

```
ggplot(gohome,aes(y=disthome, x=dcsz, fill = decide)) +
  #add bars and the preserve part keeps all bars same width
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge(preserve='single'),
           data=gohome.disthome,aes(x=dcsz,y=meandisthome))+
  #overlay data points
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
  #add error bars of means
  geom_errorbar(data=gohome.disthome,stat="Identity",
                position=position_dodge(0.9,preserve = "single"),
                aes(x=dcsz, fill = decide,y=meandisthome,
                    ymin=meandisthome-sedisthome,ymax=meandisthome+sedisthome),
                width=0.3)+
  #flip axis
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

I've also tried using `position_dodge2` instead of `position_dodge` for different combos and `preserve='total'`, but that doesn't solve it either. Either the points stay the say or they become a complete scatter with no separation. I had the idea to use `position_dodge2` and `preserve='total'` from the following link since my problem is very similar (not sure why mine isn't working): https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2712

Can someone please help me fix my code? I need to points to line up perfectly for all error bars.

Comment: I feel this is a perfect example where one fares better using boxplots instead of bars (or don't use them at all), because the bars do misrepresent the data in this case. you then would't need error bars any more, and only have two geoms to align.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you missed to set the grouping variable in `geom_errobar` and `geom_point`. From the [docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html):

> position_dodge() requires the grouping variable to be be specified in the global or geom_* layer.

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(gohome,aes(y=disthome, x=dcsz)) +
  #add bars and the preserve part keeps all bars same width
  geom_bar(stat="identity",
           position=position_dodge(), 
           data=gohome.disthome,
           aes(x=dcsz, y=meandisthome, fill = decide)) +
  #overlay data points
  geom_point(aes(group = decide), position=position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  #add error bars of means
  geom_errorbar(data=gohome.disthome,stat="Identity",
                position=position_dodge(width = 0.9),
                aes(x=dcsz, 
                    group = decide,
                    y=meandisthome,ymin=meandisthome-sedisthome,ymax=meandisthome+sedisthome), width = 0.5)+
  #flip axis
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

**EDIT** After a lot of googling and checking out several combos the best solution I can come up with to get bars of the same width is to simply fill up the dataframe using `tidyr::complete(decide, dcsz)`.

```r
gohome <- data.frame(decide,dcsz,disthome) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(decide, dcsz)

gohome.disthome <- gohome %>% group_by(dcsz,decide) %>%
  summarise(meandisthome = mean(na.omit(disthome)), sedisthome=sd(na.omit(disthome))/sqrt(n()))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'dcsz' (override with `.groups` argument)

ggplot(gohome,aes(y=disthome, x=dcsz)) +
  #add bars and the preserve part keeps all bars same width
  geom_bar(stat="identity",
           position=position_dodge(), 
           data=gohome.disthome,
           aes(x=dcsz, y=meandisthome, fill = decide)) +
  #overlay data points
  geom_point(aes(group = decide), position=position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  #add error bars of means
  geom_errorbar(data=gohome.disthome,stat="Identity",
                position=position_dodge(width = 0.9),
                aes(x=dcsz, 
                    group = decide,
                    y=meandisthome,ymin=meandisthome-sedisthome,ymax=meandisthome+sedisthome), width = 0.5)+
  #flip axis
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Stefan, I appreciate your help. Your suggestion helps me get the points to align, but then I am still left with the problem of the bar width. I would like the bars to all be exactly the same width, instead of the 'medium' category having thicker bars than the 'smaller' category. This is why I tried including the 'preserve="single"', which isn't working for geom_point. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @catcool7. I hate this postioning stuff. (; I just made an edit. As you already figured out there are a lot of issues related to the problem of aligning several geoms. The best solution I could come up with is to simply complete the dataset to include all combos of the the categorical variables. Best

Comment: Thank you @stefan! Great solution for what I wanted. I spent so many hours googling that I had given up and posted it on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Dodging can be a pain. Given your use case, and assuming you aren't using facets for anything else, it may be simpler to use them instead:

```
ggplot(gohome, 
       aes(x = decide, y = disthome)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = "mean",
               aes(fill = decide),
               width = 1) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar") + # default summary function is mean_se()
  facet_grid(forcats::fct_rev(dcsz) ~ ., switch = "y") +
  coord_flip() +
  
  # optional: aesthetic changes to imitate the original look
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "pt"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0))
```

(Note that I didn't use the summary data frame either, as the summary stats in ggplot2 suffice.)

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you @Z.Lin! I really appreciate this fix. I spent too long trying to figure it out myself and had given up.